# Stop Custom Image from rotating

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are using forge viewer to display Revit files. We want to display a custom image as background. We tried different options. However, the image is rotating and we don't want the custom image to rotate. Would it be possible to add the custom image using code to the Environment and avoid rotating? We also tried using three.js mesh. It displays the image but the image is rotating. What can we do to avoid the custom image from rotating?

Thank you for your help.

The following is our sample code using Mesh. It displays the image but it rotates.

```
const imgTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/bsd-speclink-logo.jpg')
var transparentMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({

     map: imgTexture,

    color: 0xffffff,
    opacity: 0.1,
    transparent: true
   })

    viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial('transparent',transparentMaterial,true)
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 40, 40, 40);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, transparentMaterial)
    mesh.position.set(60, -60, 0);
    viewer.impl.scene.add(mesh)
    viewer.impl.invalidate(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/transparent-background-viewer-long-last) to set the canvas transparent so you can slip in a background underneath.

Or try the skybox workaround [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-skybox-and-camera-animation) to emulate background in the canvas.